# Is there any utilization of "GPU in CPU" (e.g. skylake) if there is stand alone GPU in the computer?

Tags: cpu, gpu

Intel dedicated roughly half of the die space, on their newest Skylake processor, to the GPU.

Is there any utilization of that GPU, when there is a graphic card in a desktop computer?

Are there any applications / games that use both GPUs? (e.g. one for graphics and other for physics?
Will possibly  be?

Comment: This entirely depends.  DX12 would allow both GPUs to be used, but that is dependent on the application to use.

Answer (score 0):

integrated gpu is always on. If you run a game in full screen on the external gpu, the workload of the internal gpu is at minimum, if you are not playing or encoding a video in the background. but never zero in terms of utilization so you can't disable it. two gpus will be utilized in new generation chips, with directx 12